# Use Mathematica as an equation editor

Tags: formatting

I am having difficulty using Mathematica as an equation editor because it wants to evaluate the equation, instead of just format it. For example:

$\frac{D\text{Decay Rate}}{R_A^2 \left(\frac{\eta }{2}+\frac{7}{96 \eta }+O\left(\frac{1}{\eta ^2}\right)-\frac{1}{8}\right)}$

Is generating complaints.

Is there anyway to do this, or is it back to Latex?

Comment: Why would you want to type Latex code in *Mathematica*? Anyways, if you don't want to evaluate it just make it a text cell

Comment: @Felix If it is formatted as text then it does not look the same as TraditionalForm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the equation in `TraditionalForm[HoldForm[expr]]`.

For example (I can't quite decipher your equation)

```
TraditionalForm[
 HoldForm["Decay Rate"/(Subscript[R, a]^2 
   (η/2 + 7/(96 η) + O*(1/η^2) - 1/8))]]
```

produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can further wrap this in `Magnify` or `Style` to control the color, font or size.

You can double click on the output cell to hide the verbose expression that creates the output.